# How to use a public API?

Tags: api, web

I'm a pretty amateur programmer and i need more coding that is not related to school. I live in the bay area and came across the Bay Area Rapid Transit's API. But their documentation sucks! I want to build a simple webpage that uses the bike flag (seen here: http://api.bart.gov/docs/sched/stnsched.aspx) to display when someone can bring their bicycle on the subway. I've never used an API before so i'm pretty lost. I've written simple programs with c++, java and python.

how should i get started? What languages are good? What would this simple web app look like?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Actually, I voted to close as: *It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*

Comment: Off topic? Really?  Here I had typed up a little javascript program for him to get started with and I can't post it...

Comment: @BioBuckyBall - I agree. For the case of a beginner, it might be unreasonable for them to define what they are looking for because they may not know it. I made my answer a wiki. Feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 3):

Their documentation isn't *too* bad. If you are thinking about getting into programming professionally, prepare for bad documentation, and documentation far worse than this.

Basically, BART will give you an [XML file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) of data via a URI. The query string of the URI is acting as input parameters. This is their URI in their example:

http://api.bart.gov/api/sched.aspx?**cmd**=*stnsched*&**orig**=*12th*&**key**=*MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V*&l=1

The bold parts of the URI indicate the parameter names as you can see in your documentation. The italics part indicates the value of that parameter. So we see:

- cmd = stnsched
- orig = 12th
- key = MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V

Changing these values in the URI will yield different results in the XML file (except for key, I think. This appears to be a registration process for using the API).

Now, as far as language - use whatever you feel comfortable with. XML is a fairly universal data type. C#, Ruby, Java, Python, etc all have excellent ability to work with XML with their given Framework (Like the .NET Framework BCL for C#). There are many other languages as well.